# Javascript/jquery second prompt value filling previous prompt value

Tags: javascript, jquery, prompt

I'm creating a mini game that has a user roll to randomly create two dogs with various genetics. Everything is done front-end because I have no knowledge of back-end. Once the user has rolled the dog they want, they click a button to keep that dog. When that button is clicked, I want a prompt to pop up to ask them what they want to name this dog. The only problem is when they roll the second dog and name it, that name overwrites the first dog's name.

Here's the code for when the keep male button is pressed. The female version is identical except for the variable names:

```
$('#keepMale').on('click', function() {
    //remove any remaining rolls left to the user
    maleCount = 0;

    //prompt the user to name their new dog
    newMale.name = prompt("Name your new male:");

    //add the current dog to the user's dog array
    ownedDogs[dogCount] = newMale;

    //change the dog count to reflect the user's number of dogs
    dogCount++;

    //changes the male rolls alert to reflect that a male has been chosen
    $('#maleRolls').text('You\'ve chosen your first male!');
    $('#maleRolls').removeClass('alert-warning alert-danger');
    $('#maleRolls').addClass('alert-success');

    //change the male kept variable to reflect that a male has been kept
    maleKept = 1;

    //run bothKept to check if both keep buttons have been clicked
    bothKept(femaleKept, maleKept);
});
```

This is what I'm using later to call the name value:

```
$('#dogList').html('<div class="alert alert-info dogCells"><strong>'
 + ownedDogs[0].name + '</strong></div><div class="alert alert-info dogCells"><strong>' 
+ ownedDogs[1].name + '</strong></div>');
```

Both divs show up the exact same, and even when I check the values on the console directly after they're applied, they show up the same. The ownedDogs array is global to the document and every other value is working properly. I'm not sure what I've done wrong here.

I'm sorry if this is too specific a question, I've just spent a lot of time searching and comparing my code to working code, and I can't find what I've done wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You aren't scoping your variables with `var`

Comment: All variables in these snippets have already been previously defined, so I thought I didn't need to add     var.

Comment: the ´newMale´ variable is declared outside the event? Actually you might use var notation before setting this value to the ownedDogs array, if not it ll be always pointing to the referred object.

Comment: Yes, newMale was defined at the beginning of the function this event is inside of using the same Dog constructor I use for all the dog objects.